# Adding a parameter to GetItems in DotNetNuke sample Module

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

Below is the code from the DotNetNuke Sample module that gets a collection of items from the database that belong to a particular module. What I want is add a second parameter for it filter by. I'm guessing this has something to do with modifying the scope item.cs class but am not sure how exactly.

```
    public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems(int moduleId)
    {
        IEnumerable<Item> t;
        using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance())
        {
            var rep = ctx.GetRepository<Item>();
            t = rep.Get(moduleId);
        }
        return t;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some sample code from my SignalRChat module that uses DAL2 (http://signalrchat.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/71473#1272188)

```
public IEnumerable<Message> GetRecentMessages(int moduleId, int hoursBackInTime, int maxRecords)
        {
            var messages = (from a in this.GetMessages(moduleId) where a.MessageDate.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow).TotalHours <= hoursBackInTime select a).Take(maxRecords).Reverse();

            return messages.Any() ? messages : null;
        }
```

That is one approach, you can also use a SQL statement within the controller as well (http://signalrchat.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/71473#1272186)

```
public ConnectionRecord GetConnectionRecordByConnectionId(string connectionId)
        {
            ConnectionRecord t;
            using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance())
            {
                var connections = ctx.ExecuteQuery<ConnectionRecord>(CommandType.Text,
                                                       string.Format(
                                                           "select top 1 * from {0}{1}SignalRChat_ConnectionRecords where ConnectionId = '{2}'",
                                                           _databaseOwner,
                                                           _objectQualifier,
                                                          connectionId)).ToList();

                if (connections.Any())
                {
                    t = connections[0];
                }
                else
                    return null;
            }
            return t;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it in DAL2 is using the .Find() method.  This is good if you want to query on an indexed field in your table and you don't care about caching scope:

```
public IEnumerable<Item> GetItemByName(int moduleId, string itemname)
{
    IEnumerable<Item> t;
    using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance())
    {
        var rep = ctx.GetRepository<Item>();
        t = rep.Find("WHERE ModuleId = @0 AND ItemName LIKE @1", moduleId, itemname);
    }
    return t;
}
```